# Installed gmate but themes and plugins now showing up in gedit

Tags: 11.04, gedit

I am installing [gmate](https://github.com/gmate/gmate) on Ubuntu 11.04 (Gnome 3):

```
sudo apt-get install gedit-gmate
```

But gedit is untouched (there should appear new themes and plugins).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those plugins don't work with GNOME 3. In fact, most of the old Gedit plugins don't work with the latest Gedit 3.

Update: here's a working plugins list for Gedit 3: http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins . And the old Gedit 2 plugins: http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/PluginsOld

Comment: Can I install Gedit 2.x? Or I should wait for gmate updating?

Comment: @fl00r I didn't try it but in theory you should be able to install Gedit 2.x as long as there aren't other Gnome3 applications that depend on it. As for the other part of your question: some plugins might never be updated or they can't work anymore, it depends on their original maintainers as the Gmate project isn't responsible for creating the extensions.

Answer (score 2):

The migration of gmate is in progress.

You can try it here:

https://github.com/mereghost/gmate

Answer (score 1):

here are some [gedit 3 plugins](https://github.com/madhums/gedit3-plugins). Just copy them to `~/.local/share/gedit/plugins`